# Manipulate numbers in a specific range

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

My core problem is to manipulate account numbers written in different ways to be formatted in the same way. The account numbers consists of a clearing number and an account number. For example:

The written account number is: Clearing 8357, and account number is 1234567.

First of all, the code needs to identify that 8357 is the range 8300-8400. This means that the code should add a "9" between the clearing number and the account number. In some ranges there are no 9 at all and the clearing should be left as it is.

Second, the account number in total needs to be exactly 15 numbers long, so in our case we need to add zeros between the clearing number and the account number.

In our case the code should change the written account number from 8357 1234567 to "835790001234567"

Any help along the way would be deeply appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, to be perfectly honest with you this issue is way out of my league to solve and i have not done that much about it since i dont know where to start. Like i said in the post, any help along the way would be deeply appreciated (and i have searched this and other forums for solutions)

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer in this forum, and would require someone to code "for you". That is not what this forum is based upon. We can help, but you have to define specific problem in your code for us to be able to help. Note also that you can do what you want without using vba at all by using default excel formulas, if you are not familiar with vba, I'd suggest experimenting with `IF` and `VLOOKUP` formulas.

Comment: Is the *clearing* number always 4 digits long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without VBA**

Put the clearing number in **A1** and the account number in **B1**; then in **C1** enter:

```
=A1&IF(AND(A1<=8400,A1>=8300),9,"")
```

and in **D1** enter:

```
=B1 & REPT("0",15-LEN(B1)-LEN(C1)) & C1
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Gary's Student, thank you for this, even if it's not exactly what i needed it's a big help. The problem is (and as usual) user-related, since some users enter the full clearing number of the range including the 9, and some dont. But i understand your formula and i will try to fix the rest myself, i need to learn this at some point anyway :). Thank you!